# Converting Multiple columns into Doubletype in Spark Scala Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark Dataframe that contains 100 columns. All the columns are String. I would like to cast some of the columns into DoubleType. But I do no want to cast them one by one, using:

```
val  df = df.withColumn("colname_1",col("colname_1").cast(DoubleType))
     df.withColumn("colname_2",col("colname_2").cast(DoubleType))
```

I want to put all the concerned columns in a configuration file as a list and use that configuration file to cast them into Doubletype. Do you have any idea how I can do it quickly with using scala ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
val df = Seq(("1.0", "2.0", "3.0")).toDF("colname_1", "colname_2", "acolname_3")
val hundredColumnNamesFromConfig = Seq("colname_1", "colname_2", "colname_3")
val hundredColumnNamesFromConfigSet = Set(hundredColumnNamesFromConfig:_*)
val newCols = df.columns.map{c => if(hundredColumnNamesFromConfigSet.contains(c))
                                    col(c).cast("double")
                                  else
                                    col(c)}
val new_df = df.select(newCols:_*)
```

Comment: Hello again, thank you for your answer. I tried your solution. It cast all the columns in hundredColumnNamesFromConfig into Double. But suppose in df, I have "colname_4", "colname_5", "colname_6" that are string. I would like also to have them in new_df but not casted. With your solution I only have columns mentioned in hundredColumnNamesFromConfig . In my case case I still want to have a dataframe with all the columns in df, with only those in hundredColumnNamesFromConfig casted

Comment: @MameSilmangDiouf I've updated the code to include the missing columns.

Answer (score 1):

Column list can be casted with `foldLeft` function:

```
val df = Seq(("1.0", "2.0", "3.0")).toDF("colname_1", "colname_2", "acolname_3")
val hundredColumnNamesFromConfig = Seq("colname_1", "colname_2", "colname_3")

val convertedDF = hundredColumnNamesFromConfig
  .foldLeft(df)((accumulatedDF, columnName) => accumulatedDF.withColumn(columnName, col(columnName).cast(DoubleType)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what does accumulatedDF and columnName mean ? It is not defined in your code ?

Comment: Both are just a names, defined inside 'foldLeft' function, and available only in scope of this function. Maybe, you can check how 'foldLeft' for collections works.

Comment: Be aware that if your number of columns to be cast increases your performance will drop substantially due to a new projection for each withColumn - prefer the solution from Sreejith k that does all those casts in a single projection.